# CSS not working in Safari when I click on a link

Tags: css, safari

I have a webpage that works well with all browsers except Safari.  When I first load my page in Safari, the frot page displays all the styling corresponding to that page.  However, when I click on a link to go to another page the styling for the colors and images is not recognized.  I wonder if somebody knows what can be causing this.  Thanks in advance.

This class named "TableLeftNav" seems to disappear:

```
<div class="ui-layout-west container border TableLeftNav ui-layout-pane-west" style="position: absolute; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; right: auto; z-index: 0; left: 0px; width: 248px; top: 180px; bottom: 0px; height: 71px; display: block; visibility: visible;">
```

and the CSS for that class is:

```
.TableLeftNav { background-color: #003c79; width: 275px; border: #003c79; }
```

Comment: It may be to do with your paths to your style sheets - to get more help you really need to include some example code.

Comment: Hi Billy.  It is just a regular path.  <link id="cssCompany"rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/style.css" />

Comment: What I have found in the developer is that it does not see some classes at all.

Comment: We need to see the css and some example html

Comment: This class named "TableLeftNav" seems to disappear: <div class="ui-layout-west container border TableLeftNav ui-layout-pane-west" style="position: absolute; margin-top: 0px; margin-right: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px; margin-left: 0px; right: auto; z-index: 0; left: 0px; width: 248px; top: 180px; bottom: 0px; height: 71px;  display: block; visibility: visible;">  and the CSS for that class is:  .TableLeftNav
{
  background-color: #003c79;
  width: 275px;
  border: #003c79;
}

Comment: The TableLeftNav class is not seen by the browser depending on the developer tool.

Comment: I just found out that Safari is not reading the href